# Why is the Makefile not generating the objects?

Tags: c, object, makefile

When I compilate the library (4 folders: 1 inc -> mylib.h, lib, obj, src -> mylib.c) with this makefile:

makefile:

```
CC = gcc
AR = ar
CFLAGS = -c -Wall

all: Release

Release: my

my: my.o
 $(AR) rc lib/libmy.a obj/my.o
 bash gen_pc.sh

obj/my.o: src/my.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/my.c -o obj/my.o

clean:
 rm -f obj/my.o lib/libmy.a lib/libmy.pc
```

gen_pc:

```
current_path=`readlink -e .`
cat > lib/libmy.pc << EOM
prefix=$current_path
includedir=\${prefix}/inc
libdir=\${prefix}/lib

Name: my
Description: My library
Version: 1.0
Cflags: -I\${includedir}
Libs: -L\${libdir} -lmy
Libs.private: -lm
EOM
```

no .o files / objects are generated in lib folder even if when running make in terminal I don't receive any errors:

```
make

gcc -c -Wall src/my.c -o obj/my.o
ar rc lib/libmy.a obj/my.o
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: one error: `my.o` is not the proper target, should be `obj/my.o`

Comment: Is the `makefile` you show really the same you're using? Because the lack of indentation of commands would make it invalid.

Comment: I changed the indentation

Comment: Thank you Jean, unfortunately the obj folder stays empty.

Comment: Maybe I should change the order, because in the beginning I have no my.o?

Comment: `my: my.o`... That's not the correct path of the object file?

Comment: Also, if you create the file `lib/libmy.a` then the target name should be that as well (and remember to update all the rules where you use `my`).

Comment: `my: my.o` => `my: obj/my.o` too

Comment: have you tried to run `gcc -c -Wall src/my.c -o obj/my.o` directly? what happens?. Something has to be created in obj, or a compiler error message has to be printed.

Comment: Another thing you should read about is [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules). Using them would mean you could have the two rules `lib/libmy.a: obj/my.o` and `obj/my.obj: src/my.c`, without any command to build anything as that would be handled implicitly. Just set the correct `CFLAGS` (without `-c`) and you're done.